# Displaying a TextField on user interaction

Tags: java, swing

I want to **display a TextField only when user has entered a value in Input field**

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PlayingAround {

    JFrame frame;
    JTextField display;
    JTextField input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayingAround obj = new PlayingAround();
        obj.create();
    }

    private void create() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        display = new JTextField();
        input = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.setVisible(false);

        input.addKeyListener(new Listener());
        frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, display);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, input);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class Listener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            display.setVisible(true);
            display.setText(input.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

But my problem is that the ***Display JTextField*** doesn't becomes visible until there are some events like **Resizing the Window, Minimizing and maximizing the Window**.

I tried calling **frame.repaint()** in the keyReleased Method but even it has not helped.

Comment: Since you are using a layout manager, you might need to call validate() on your content pane.  This is probably happening when you maximize/minimize the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that holds the JTextField after placing the text field component in the container.  The `revalidate()` call sends a request to the container's layout managers to re-layout its components. The `repaint()` then requests that the JVM request of the paint manager to redraw the newly laid out container and its child components. The repaint() is not always needed but is usually a good idea.

Also, don't use a KeyListener for this, but rather a DocumentListener on the first text component's Document. This way, if the user empties the first text component, you can make the second text component disappear if desired. Also, text can be entered without key presses, and you want to allow for that.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest a good book for Java GUI development ?

Comment: @Snehasish: I'm no GUI pro, but most of what I learned about Swing was learned through the [Java Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) and this site. Also I recommend [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) by Haase and Guy.